# how to display a stack of image followed by name in order

Tags: java, image, jlabel

i wan to ask that if my machine got 1000/10000 of image and each image is named follow by order (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg .... 10000.jpg) , how to do it to let it display follow th order ?

i saw a lot of question on internet that they put it on the JLabel but many of them say it won't work . i have even try a few method to let it display like javascript but it is not the result i want.

I wish the program is running like 0.5 seconds a time and display the image followed the image number.

Can anyone guild me through this ? thanks in advance

==================================================================================

update : this is my javascript code

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="rotating image" width="600" height="500" id="rotator">

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  // change to match image ID
//var imageDir = 'images/';                          // change to match images folder
var delayInSeconds = 1;                            // set number of seconds delay
// list image names
var images = ['1.jpg','2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'];

// don't change below this line
var num = 0;
var changeImage = function() {
    var len = images.length;
    rotator.src = images[num++];
    if (num == len) {
        num = 0;
    }
};
setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried in javascript?

Comment: dear @subirkumarsao , i have update the code on above . thanks in advance for helping .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you need to preload images, to do it, you can add them in hidden div. Then replace your original image with it.Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ViewImage</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
var img_num = 1;
$(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
    var img = $('#hiden-img');
    if(img[0].complete==true)
        $('#real-image').attr('src', img.attr('src'));
    img_num++;
    if(img_num>10000)img_num=1;
    img.attr('src', '/img/'+img_num+'.jpg');

}, 500);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="hiden-img" style="display:none;"/>
<img id="real-image" src="/img/1.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

try it like this. Download jquery and place it in your site, replace paths "/path/to/img" (2 times) and "/path/to/jquery" to your real paths. this should do the trick.

you do not need to refresh page every second. You do not need to refresh it all. 
It's works on my site.

Comment: i have put the code u recomended into my code .. but it didnt display anything. is there any place i do wrong ? sorry form y ignorance due to i not really know about the javascript. and thanks for your hep

Comment: it can only display the image i declare in the "var image". if i have 10000 image , how to do that . i have try using a for loop but it failed .. any suggesstion @El'